# Android Push Messaging (GCM) Returning InvalidRegistration Error

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

We are moving away from Urban Airship for Android push messaging to GCM (which Urban Airship also uses).  We have found that all of our push attempts return an error:

```
"success":0,
"failure":1,
"canonical_ids":0,
"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

We are using the App ID that Urban Airship is using (and is from the Google console) and the Device Tokens that do work properly with Urban Airship.

We have noticed that the tokens from the application are short - around 40 characters - but we have read that GCM tokens are well over 100 characters.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The Urban Airship Device Tokens are a made-up, Urban Airship construct. Outside of Urban Airship they do not correlate to anything. Urban Airship stores an association between their Device Tokens and the actual GCM registration ID on their server. If you want to migrate away from Urban, you either need to:

1. get them to export all of your GCM registration IDs for you
2. try to export them yourself via their CSV export functionality
3. For every device token you (seem to) have, call their APID API to get the GCM ID: http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua.html#get--api-apids-(APID)
4. Otherwise you'll have to have the new version of your app re-register for GCM, the obvious fallback there being dormant users who don't upgrade and/or open your app after upgrade will not be re-registered, unless you do some trickery with a `BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver` ;)